# Cardinality of set and its power set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Prove that for any set $X$ we have the $|X| < |\mathcal{P}(X)|$ (power set of $X$)

How would you prove this using the definitions of bijection, surjection, and injection?

Also, does this mean when we have the empty set $X = \{\}$, then $|X| < |\mathcal{P}(X)|$ as well? Would they not be equal?

Comment: Hint for the finite case for getting an intuition for why this is true: each individual element of $X$ is an element of $P(X)$ (as a singleton set).

Comment: I think this has been asked here before.  It's a standard diagonal argument.

Comment: To T. Bongers: It would still hold that |X| < |P(X)| when x = {} because n = 0 so |P(X)| = 2^0 = 1, correct?

Comment: In the case of the empty set $X$, there are no elements in $X$, but there is one element in $\mathcal P(X)$, namely the empty set.

Comment: For a proof different from the diagonal argument, see [here](http://mathoverflow.net/a/47022/6085).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f:X\to \mathcal P(X)$ is injective.  Let $A=\{x\in X: x\not\in f(x)\}$.  It can be shown by contradiction that $A$ is not in the image of $f$.  If $A=f(a)$ then either $a\in f(a)$ or $a\not\in f(a)$, and a contradiction ensues either way.

Sometimes you see the proof written like this: Assume $f:X\to \mathcal P(X)$ is injective and surjective.  Then deduce a contradiction.  But phrasing the proof as a whole as a proof by contradiction, rather than just having that one part of the proof done by contradiction, just makes it look more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: It is not needed that $f$ is injective.

Comment: True, but I think it may be a bit easier to understand that way.